# AngularJS/JavaScript - Substring of searched term and marked it with <span>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

I have a long string, for example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis viverra diam non justo. Maecenas fermentum, sem in pharetra pellentesque, velit turpis volutpat ante, in pharetra metus odio a lectus.
```

I want create (probably) a filter, which will find specific part, mark it with span tag and return it with some number of chars before and after too (rounded to whole words).

So for our example:

Filter should be:

```
text | 'ridiculus' : 10 : 20
```

And it should returned:

```
nascetur <span class="marked">ridiculus</span> mus. Duis viverra
```

The best would be, if the filter returns array of these substrings for each occurrence of the search term.

Thanks a lot for help.

EDIT 1:
Highlighting works. Thanks. But I need also to split the string to array of substrings with highlighted search term and given number of characters before and after too.

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

- Accept search and content from DOM.
- Parse search: replace all spaces to allow multi-word search.
- Then create a regex using search value. Note to add flags `g` and `i` for recursive and case-insensitive search.
- Create a function that accepts a string and returns HTML in necessary style.
- Then replace the content string using this regex and above declared function.
- Set return value as innerHTML.

```js
document.getElementById("btnSearch").addEventListener("click", processSearch)

function processSearch(){
  var search = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
  search = search.replace(/ /g, '|');
  var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.content')
  contentDiv.innerHTML = getHighlightHTML(contentDiv.innerHTML, search);
}

function getHighlightHTML(text, search){
  var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");
  return text.replace(regex, wrapHighlight)
}

function wrapHighlight(str){
  return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>"
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  border-bottom: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<button id="btnSearch" >Search</button>

<div class="content">
  This is a <b>random test</b>, just to simulate word highlight based on search value.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can just pass your full text and searched text in the filter defined. and in span, you can take html binding. Please look the working code on jsfiddle below :
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/942RA/212/)